# How to add delay in javascript for loop using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

I want to hold the iteration of the `for-loop` until the functionality in the previous iteration gets completed. I have seen many questions about `setTimeout` but none of them has satisfied my requirement. Can anyone help me?

```js
function abcd() {
    var exArray = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0];
    var index = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < exArray.length; i++) {
        if (exArray[i] == 1) {
            addDelay(++index);

        } else {
            console.log('ended at ' + i);
        }
    }
}
```

seTimeout functionality is something like this

```
function addDelay(index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("in Timeout loop:" + index);
    }, 2000 * index);
}
```

## The expected output is

ended at 0

ended at 1

in Timeout loop:{{index}}  // wait for delay

in Timeout loop:{{index}}  // wait for delay

in Timeout loop:{{index}}  // wait for delay

ended at 5

ended at 6

ended at 7

## But output I see in my console is:

ended at 0

ended at 1

ended at 5

ended at 6

ended at 7

in Timeout loop:{{index}}  // wait for delay

in Timeout loop:{{index}}  // wait for delay

in Timeout loop:{{index}}  // wait for delay

I want the `ended at 5` to wait until timeout functionality of 3rd, 4th, 5th array indices. I need someone to help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your `setTimeout` code section is well written... try a ES6 approach: `setTimeout(() => { console.log('waiting 1 second...'); }, 1000);`

Comment: The `setTimeout` will schedule a background task and then return immediately. so your loop continues to run and after the delay the timeout function is executed, so it can't work like that. The best solution in your case might be to get rid of the for loop and replace it by a callback-loop, so after each delayed execution it call the "loop" with the next index until the end of your array.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeOut` doesn't work that way. It just registers an action to be performed at a later point of time and just continues. Once this script is over,  it will take up your queued up tasks and perform.

Check how `setTimeout` really works under the hood. Also, read more about JavaScript's Event Loop.

```js
var input = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0];

function immediateOrRegister(index) {
    if (index >= input.length) return;
    if (input[index] == 0) {
        console.log("No delay");
        immediateOrRegister(index + 1);
    } else if (input[index] == 1) {
        console.log("Timing out for atleast " + 2 * index + " seconds");
        setTimeout(function() {
            immediateOrRegister(index + 1)
        }, 2000 * index);
    }
}

immediateOrRegister(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand your question, please see this Fiddle. https://fiddle.jshell.net/qw6qp7pm/1/ (Using Underscore JS `delay()` http://underscorejs.org/#delay)

```
function abcd(index) {
  var exArray = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
  var index = index ? index : 0
  if (index >= exArray.length) return false

  for (var i = index; i < exArray.length; i++) {
    if (exArray[i] == 1) {
      //addDelay(++index);
      _.delay(log, 2000, i)
      break
    } else {
      console.log('ended at ' + i)
    }
  }
}

function log(index) {
  console.log("in Timeout loop:" + index)

  // RECURSE
  abcd(index + 1)
}

abcd()
```

Answer (score 0):

loop will execute continuously for its each index. as you need all your logs one-after-one, means you have to put delay for each index, whether its satisfy your condition or not.

```
function abcd() {  
    var exArray=[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0];
    var index=0;
    var message='';
    for(var i=0;i<exArray.length; i++)    {
        if(exArray[i]==1) {
           ++index;
           message='in Timeout loop:'+i;
           addDelay(index, message);
        }else{
           message='ended at '+i;
           addDelay(index, message);
        }

    }
}


function addDelay(index, message){
    setTimeout(function () {
         console.log(message);
    }, 2000*index); 
}
```